# R reactive histogram

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning the `Shiny` interface for `R` and working through the first example.

The histogram changes based on the slider input. How do I have it update continuously, while the slider is moving? Right now, it only updates when the slider stops moving.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
  # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should re-execute automatically
  #     when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
})
```

What I have tried:

```
#server.R
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input,output) {
                    x<-faithful[,2]
                    bins <- reactive({
                            seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=input$bins+1)
                    })

                    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
                    hist(x,breaks=bins(),col='darkgray',border='white')})
    })
```

Is there a way to make it react faster/real-time?

Comment: I wonder if there's some javascript behind the scene that says 'must stop on a specific value before we will update input$bins', which would be an interesting question to ask the RStudio guys (or people who really know shiny).

If that's the case, then speeding up your code won't help, but would need to inject some new javascript, if possible.

Not a solution, but now I'm curious.

Comment: There may be a reason, as while this simple histogram may be very fast, some of the drawing code may be very slow, and it is not sensible to redraw the graph on the fly (it might crash the server). As @AndrewTaylor says, must be code in `Shiny` that controls this behaviour. If you want real-time updated histograms, you might want to try some pure Javascript solutions instead of Shiny, as Shiny needs to re-draw the whole graph, but Javascript solutions may only need to update what's changed.

Comment: It appears that Shiny uses `Ion.RangeSlider` javascript library to create the actual slider. If you read the page http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html, you'll see that the javascript library has both `onChange` and `onFinish` event, the former will call code whenever value changes, but the latter will call code only when user releases mouse. It appears that Shiny uses the latter option, but there is no user-facing option to change this behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough Javascript yet. Thank you guys for your comments!

Comment: Helpful resource from Shiny: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html
Also, Homer White has a package that might help you, it has a `customSliderInput()` function that I never tried but if I remember correctly it lets you customize the rate at which the input is updated https://github.com/homerhanumat/shinyCustom

Comment: @daattali, the `shinyCustom` package looks to provide an quick, easy solution to the posted problem. I hadn't come across either resources prior, so thanks for posting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dean's response I investigated the `shinyCustom` package in github.

Here is my solution:

```
#Shiny UI
library(shiny)
library(shinyCustom)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyCustom(slider_delay = "0"), #make a call to shinyCustom, where there is no delay
      customSliderInput("bins", #Use customSliderInput instead of sliderInput
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

App now updates as you move the slider