# Real time updating of ui values - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

From `ui.r`, I want to make the max value of the second `sliderInput` the current value of the first `sliderInput`. How do I do this?

```
sliderInput("blockSize", "block size", min = 1, max = 12, value = 8, step = 1)

#max should be the current value of blockSize instead of 12
sliderInput("offset", "offset", min = 1, max = 12 , value = 1, step = 1)
```

Comment: Use `observeEvent` and `updateSliderInput` on the server side to dynamically update the second slider depending on the value of the first one

Comment: thanks, isn't there a way to make this update reactively on the user side? I want the update to be fast.

Comment: The update is very fast. If you want the second slider to change WHILE you are dragging the first one, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420425/r-reactive-histogram#comment62347964_37420425 for a solution. There is no way to do this completely in ui.R unless you modify the raw javascript object for the slider (as I mentioned in the link, Shiny uses `Ion.RangeSlider` for the underlying implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code that updates the second slider input depending on the first one. The key is

```
observeEvent(input$bins, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins2", max=input$bins)
})
```

Complete code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         sliderInput("bins2",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$bins, {
        updateSliderInput(session, "bins2", max=input$bins)
    })

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```