# Is it possible to display an R Shiny sliderInput being reactive *during* dragging?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

I'm using a Shiny [sliderInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sliderInput.html) and I'd like to prevent it sending updates when dragging, but update when the mouse button is released. Is this possible?

At present, it seems to update periodically *during* dragging.

Comment: Technically it should be possible, as the sliderInput uses Ion.RangeSlider under the hood, and Ion.RangeSlider can be setup to run event `onFinish` instead of `onChange`. I think I've seen a similar question before but cannot find it right now. http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

Comment: Here is the question I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420425/r-reactive-histogram

Comment: Thanks @warmoverflow. Looks like digging into the JavaScript might be my only option. I'll play with it.