# sliderInput value change as slider dragged

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I have an app currently where the input$sliderInputID only changes when the mouse is released. Is it possible to have these values change **as the slider is being dragged**?

a demo app:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d_mean <- reactive({
      input$sliderInputID
    }) 
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      x <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=d_mean(), sd=1)
      plot(density(x))
    })
  },
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("sliderInputID", "Mean:", min = -5, max = 5, value = 0, step= 0.1),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

In this case, the plot should update as the slider is being dragged, not only when the mouse is released.

**Edit:**
There is a similar question here: [R reactive histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420425/r-reactive-histogram)
However, I'm still interested whether another solution is available using only the shiny library, since that answer was posted in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provide is the quickest and cleanest way to what you want. That package is definitely still viable -- if you're worried about it disappearing then fork it on GitHub and install from your repo:

```
# devtools::install_github("homerhanumat/shinyCustom")
library("shiny")
library("shinyCustom")

shinyApp(
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = input$sliderInputID, sd = 1)
      plot(density(x))
    })

  },
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyCustom(slider_delay = "0"),
    customSliderInput("sliderInputID", "Mean:", min = -5, max = 5, value = 0, step = 0.1),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```